# Electron GET request from LOCALHOST

Tags: javascript, jquery, request, localhost, electron

I'm trying to GET a response from a web server that I run on Localhost(`127.0.0.1`), Exactly form this URL: `http://127.0.0.1:3125/ping`.
The request is invoked by an html file that look like this, loaded in an Electron app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $.get( "127.0.0.1:3215/ping", function( data ) {
              console.log( data );
            });
        }
    );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However using the DevTools(console) while in the app, I can see that the response is always `GET http://localhost:3215/ping 404 (NOT FOUND)` and if I try to request a page, not in localhost(like `http:google.com`), the request is always successful.
And even if a try to start the request(on localhost) from my browser console, it is always successful.

I can't understand why electron behaves like this.

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the protocol you want to use for the request, http:// or https://.

```
$.get( "http://127.0.0.1:3215/ping", function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
});
```